# D3 tickValues not working

Tags: d3.js

I have following D3 axis:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
.rangePoints([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.tickValues(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
.orient("bottom");
```

working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/akshayKhot/1vusrdvc/

The tickValues are not showing other than the first one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a range value for every one of your ordinal values:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
    .range([0, 1/4 * width, 2/4 * width, 3/4 * width, width]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39xy8nwd/

Comment: I see. Thank you for the working solution. If I try that with linear scale, it fails. Can I do linear to ordinal conversion? `var x = d3.scale.linear().domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]).range([0, width]);`

Comment: @AkshayKhot Initially it was not working for linearchart. After giving an empty `.tickFormat(n =>  n )` it works. http://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/k17ayx0s/1/